# Showing "Launching Emulator" in a small window but emulator has already started and running

Tags: android, flutter

I opened virtual device list and clicked one of it to start. A small window popped up saying "Launching Emulator".
After sometimes later the emulator showed up, cool booted and working fine.

But the small window still says "Launching Emulator/Starting AVD". It doesn't have any close icon to close it.
Other background process disappeared after they completed but "Launching Emulator/Starting AVD" still stays there.
https://ibb.co/s14jkDZ
Current AS version 2021.1.1 Patch 1
If its a duplicate question, let us know

Answer (score 1):

I think it is bug from studio.. I also face the same issue... To fix the problem, I just go to the task manager and under the Android task sheet, close that service by using End task..